# check and correct xml syntax in perl

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

I have a task to correct the syntax of xml files if they are not well formatted. Currently I am doing this task manually. Is there any way to validate the syntax of `XML` file, if XML is not well formatted then correct it to well formatted?

Is it possible to validate and correct with `Perl` script?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no algorithm that could reliably take arbitrary non-well-formed XML and produce well-formed XML that reflected the original intent.  It is easy to construct non-well-formed XML that could have many different interpretations... how does the correction code decide which one is right?  What you are asking for is equivalent to writing a Java (or Perl) compiler that accepts invalid code and "corrects" it.  If we had that, syntax errors would be a thing of the past.

Comment: Thanks Jim. That make sense.
Can't we check whether opening and closing tags are correct, if not then correct them?

Comment: Check whether what...?

Comment: @Maverick143 — No. Reread Jim's original comment again.

Comment: @JimGarrison: On the other hand, all significant web browsers make a good attempt to correct malformed XHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aParser) is a validating parser. You can use it to determine if the XML is valid.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
if (eval { $parser->parse_file($qfn) }) {
   print "ok\n";
} else {
   print "error:\n$@";
}
```

---

Automatically correcting XML is another matter. It's impossible to automatically fix bad XML without making huge assumptions. For example, there's no way to know whether

```
<foo>/bar<baz/</foo>
```

was meant to be

```
<foo>/bar&lt;baz/</foo>
```

or

```
<foo>/bar<baz/></foo>
```

or even something else.

XML::LibXML does have an option to automatically fix/ignore some errors. Who knows if it makes the same assumption you do. Use

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( recover => $recover );
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($in_qfn);
$doc->toFile($out_qfn);
```

Use `1` for `$recover` if you want the parser to be warn when it fixes a problem.
Use `2` for `$recover` if you want the parser to fix problems silently.
No matter what you use for `$recover`, it will still throw an exception if it encounters an unrecoverable error.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [XML::Liberal](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLiberal): "Super liberal XML parser that parses broken XML", and see if it works for you.